# Выкладываю первый раз на боевой сервер, не дает сделать миграции

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, развертывание

Добрый день. Пол ночи убил - первый раз развертывал проект на серваке.
Возникла проблема. Установи: убунту, постгре, виртуал енв и все нужные пакеты для проекта. После того как залил с гитхаба проект - python3 manage.py makemigrations выдает следующее:

```
(notarius_online) notarius_online@NotariusOnLine:~/notarius_online$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "mainapp_city" does not exist
LINE 1: ...napp_city"."name", "mainapp_city"."ip_alias" FROM "mainapp_c...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/notarius_online/Site/urls.py", line 25, in <module>
    url(r'^', include('mainapp.urls', namespace='home'))
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/notarius_online/mainapp/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mainapp.views import HomeView, OrderView, LoginView, LogoutView
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/notarius_online/mainapp/views.py", line 93, in <module>
    class OrderView(TemplateView):
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/notarius_online/mainapp/views.py", line 103, in OrderView
    for d in cities:
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 894, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 884, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/webapps/notarius_online/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "mainapp_city" does not exist
LINE 1: ...napp_city"."name", "mainapp_city"."ip_alias" FROM "mainapp_c...
                                                             ^

(notarius_online) notarius_online@NotariusOnLine:~/notarius_online$
```

Что делать дальше ума не приложу, ведь на компе с базой sqlite3 все нормально запускается. Что делать подскажите плиз?

upd:
До развертывания проекта все поля в models.py были описаны без null=True, blank=True. Я так понял что постгре ругалась из-за этого что не может создать таблицы так как не могла найти связи. добавил эти параметры(код ниже):

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Город')
    ip_alias = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Город по ip')

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name

    def __contains__(self, item):
    return self.ip_alias == item

    class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Город'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Города'

class CityDistricts(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True,  blank=True, verbose_name='Город')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Район')

    def __str__(self):
    return '{} - {}'.format(self.city, self.name)

    class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Район'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Районы'

class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True,  blank=True,verbose_name='Город')
    district = models.ForeignKey(CityDistricts, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Район')
    street = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, verbose_name='Улица')
    build = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True, verbose_name='Дом/Строение')
    office = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True, verbose_name='Офис/Помещение')

    def __str__(self):
    return self.city.name

    class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Геолокация'


class NotarialOffice(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name='Пользователь')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, verbose_name='Название конторы')
    notarius_FIO = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, verbose_name='Фамилия Имя Отчество')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=18,
                         validators=[RegexValidator(r'(^(\+?7|8)?[(|-]?\d{1,5}[)|-]?\d{1,3}\-?\d{1,2}\-?\d{1,2})')],
                         verbose_name='Номер телефона')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=128, null=True, verbose_name='Электронная почта')
    site_url = models.URLField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Адрес сайта')
    adress = models.OneToOneField(Location, null=True,  blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Адрес')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Работает')

    def __str__(self):
    return self.notarius_FIO

    class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Контора'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Конторы'
```

`
после этого сделал python manage.py makemigrations - и миграции прошли(c подключенной Postgre). Запустил на сервере и получил ошибку что хост отсутсвует в списке доступных - добавте в ALLOWED_HOSTS
Добавил. Запустил сервер и вылезла первая ошибка(что какие то таблицы не найдены

Comment: А зачем вы выполняете `makemigrations`? Вы после заливки на боевой сервер изменили модели и вам нужны новые миграции?

Comment: ну да, я ведь на сервак установил постгре, а при разработке использовал sqlite3. Да и ошибка эта вылазит даже если просто попытаться запустить сервер

Comment: Модели от этого меняться не должны, только настройки. Вы миграции-то запускать пробовали? А то судя по ошибке, у вас в базе нет таблиц.

Comment: если вы про python manage.py migrate - то такая же фигня. База вообще еще пустая. Я только ее поставил и сделал одну базу - db1

Comment: Да, я про неё. Она как раз и должна создать таблицы в базе.

Comment: т.е. при ее создании должны еще и таблицы сами создаца? есть пошаговая инструкция у Вас? где-то я может накосячил...?

Comment: В [переводе официального учебника](https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/) всё предельно просто и подробно описано.

Comment: Было бы неплохо приложить вывод manage.py migrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил:
закоменнтировал строки которые вызывали ошибку:

```
from mainapp.views import HomeView, OrderView, LoginView, LogoutView
File "/webapps/notarius_online/notarius_online/mainapp/views.py", line    93, in <module>
class OrderView(TemplateView):
File "/webapps/notarius_online/notarius_online/mainapp/views.py", line  103, in OrderView
for d in cities:
```

сделал миграции и раскомментировал, и все прошло хорошо. Сапсибо всем за участие!

Comment: Костыли-костылики

Comment: по другому не решил 8)